# Testcase of changing password - Unit Testing using Selenium C#

Tags: c#, selenium

I have a problem here:
I write a testcase to change password and then login with the new password. I cannot assign the new password to the variable "currentPassword" to reuse in the next testcase.
I have a solution is that put a method to change the password back to its old value in TestCleanup. But I don't want the process to appear on browser. So I run the method in a new Ghost-Driver (I tried both PhantomJS and HTMLUnit but they don't work).
Here is my code, please check that what the error is, and btw, is there any other solutions?

```
[TestMethod]
        public void test()
        {
            IWebDriver newDriver = new RemoteWebDriver(DesiredCapabilities.HtmlUnit());
            newDriver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://192.168.189.49:8099/Account/Login.cshtml");
            newDriver.FindElement(By.Id("username")).SendKeys(Constant.validAcc);
            newDriver.FindElement(By.Id("password")).SendKeys(Constant.newPass);
            newDriver.FindElement(By.XPath("//input[@value='login']")).Submit();
    }
```

Thank you much, guys.

Comment: I don't understand the question. Do you have problem storing new password? Or do you have problem with the syntax of your code (which does not have anything to do with password)? Or do you have problem with changing password back? Or do you have problem having process to appear on browser (what is appearing)?

Comment: Yes, I have problem storing new changed password to reuse in the next login.
I choose the solution that, after changing old pass to a new one, in TestCleanup I put a method to change it back to old value (this can be counted that the pass has not changed), and I don't want the method in TestCleanup to appear on browser.
The code I provide above is to show that I use ghost driver to execute the method in TestCleanup. And it shows error.
I want to ask is there any other solutions to store new password? If not, please check that whether my method in TestCleanup is right.
Thank you much.

Answer (score 0):

This is just syntax issue that you have:

```
newDriver.FindElement(By.XPath("//input[@value='login']")).Submit();
```

should be

```
newDriver.FindElement(By.XPath("//input[@value='login']")).Click();
```

Although, I don't really see that it is actually changing the password back, as it just inputs name, password, and then click the login button. The code you posted is also not a test cleanup.

Comment: yes, this is just a part of code to login back and be put in a TestMethod so that I can debug easier. Actually, it contains code to change pass and is put in TestCleanup. Btw, thank you much!

Comment: The method still does not run with an error: Unable to connect to remote server.

Comment: Do you have your Remote Server available at 127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub? If you are not using default value, specify URI for your hub in `IWebDriver newDriver = new RemoteWebDriver(new Uri("xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx"), DesiredCapabilities.HtmlUnit());`. Why not using local WebDriver, for ex: `IWebDriver newDriver = new FirefoxDriver();` instead?